# Background color to be same as text color

Tags: html, css

Currently I have the following code.

```
#Image_ID {
    color: #000066;
    font: normal 10pt Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```

This makes my Input Box white and gets rid of the border. But when a value is entered the value is a black color. What I want is so that when text is entered that it is the same color as the background so that it is virtually invisible.

Comment: Have you tried changing...the color attribute?

Comment: Do you have a demo we can look at?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
#Image_ID:focus {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Could not get that to work. But it did give me the idea of taking my original code and changing color: #000066 to  color:transparent; which worked!

Comment: @MichaelDowney I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 18):

Automatic background color to be the same as the specified `color` of the element, without specifying it manually can be done using the [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword) value for the `background` property.

```css
body {
  color: black;
  background: currentColor;
}
```

[Browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20currentColor) is excellent.

Comment: 8 years later and I see this now (: